# Bibliography in tufte-handout with plainnat

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, tufte, bibliographystyle

I'm getting an error message when I try to generate a bibliography with the following.

```
 \documentclass{tufte-handout}

%\geometry{showframe}% for debugging purposes -- displays the margins
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}


% Set up the images/graphics package
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth,totalheight=\textheight,keepaspectratio}
 \graphicspath{{graphics/}}

 \title{This is a title}
 \author[Author Name]{Author Name}
 \date{}  

 \usepackage{booktabs}


  \usepackage{units}


 \usepackage{fancyvrb}
  \fvset{fontsize=\normalsize}

 % Small sections of multiple columns
 \usepackage{multicol}

 % Provides paragraphs of dummy text
 \usepackage{lipsum}

   \newcommand{\doccmd}[1]{\texttt{\textbackslash#1}}% command name -- adds backslash automatically
  \newcommand{\docopt}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle}\textrm{\textit{#1}}\ensuremath{\rangle}}% optional command argument
  \newcommand{\docarg}[1]{\textrm{\textit{#1}}}% (required) command argument
  \newenvironment{docspec}{\begin{quote}\noindent}{\end{quote}}% command specification environment
  \newcommand{\docenv}[1]{\textsf{#1}}% environment name
  \newcommand{\docpkg}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% package name
  \newcommand{\doccls}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class name
  \newcommand{\docclsopt}[1]{\texttt{#1}}% document class option name


  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{marvosym}
  \usepackage{stmaryrd}

  \begin{document}

   \maketitle% 

   Text\footnote{\citet{Author1}.}

   \bibliography{plainnat}
   \bibliographystyle{test.bib}



   \end{document}
```

The test.bib only has two items:

```
 @article{Author1, 
   Author ={Author First}, 
   Title = {TitleFirst}, 
   Journal = {Journal 1}, 
   Volume = {1}, 
   Pages = {1--100},
   Year = {1999} }  

 @incollection{Author2,
   Author = {Author Second},
   Booktitle = {Title Second},
   Editor = {Editor Editor},
   Pages = {1--100},
   Publisher = {University 1},
   Title = {Articl},
   Year = {2005}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code contains the following chunk:

```
\bibliography{plainnat}
\bibliographystyle{test.bib}
```

I have reason to believe that it should be

```
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{test} % don't include the ".bib" filename extension
```

You wrote "I'm getting an error message ...". Didn't the error message alert you to the mix-up of instructions? E.g., didn't the error message say that BibTeX couldn't find the `plainnat.bib` bibliography file or the `test.bib.bst` bibliography style file?

A separate observation: Loading the `natbib` citation management package with the required options will be helpful too. E.g., if you need to generate authoryear-style citation call-outs, you might specify the package option `authoryear`. Conversely, if you need to generate numeric-style citation call-outs, you should specify the option `numbers`.